# How to refresh table in main page and close popup in ADF 11gr1 with in the popup

Tags: oracle-adf

I've Main page (JSPX build in ADF 11gR1) in which I'm created a popup with in a region.  In the popup I'm trying to search certain ArrayList of values and I want it to send those ArrayList values to Main page by a button click.

I was able to achieve the above requirement by invoking contextual event from the pop up Bean and handling the event in the Main Page bean. Both the beans are in pageflow scope.

Main table is bind to MainTableBinding Richtable and Popup is bind to PopupBinding RichPopup which are defined in MainPageBean.

Now in the Main page bean if I'm trying to close the popup and refresh the table through the handle contextual event, I'm unable to do it as it is throwing null Pointer error that the popupbinding and the MainTablebinding do not exist. Any help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I don't like to bind UI objects to bean but use JSFUtils in the bean to find the component. If you don't have JSFUtils (and ADFUtils) class you should be able to find with a simple web search.

Then from main page bean you can do something like:

```
RichPopup pop = (RichPopup)JSFUtils.findComponentInRoot("popupid");
if (pop != null) { 
   pop.hide();
}
```

Note there are cases where you need to specify the region id as well when locating a component by id, for example when you have many regions in main page with same popupid in each region. Use Chrome "Inspect" for example to get the id of the popup which will include the region id prefix.

You can refresh table using a similar approach:

```
ADFFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(JSFUtils.findComponentInRoot("tableId"));
```

The key is to get a copy of the JSFUtils and ADFUtils libraries for this approach to work.

Comment: I'm able to close the popup but for some reason the main table does not get refreshed at all... I can see that the component is found.. but no luck :(

Comment: Try to get a handle to the iterator on the table and re-execute the query and/or refresh the iterator. Then refresh the component using above code.

Comment: the iterator is created by bean data control.. Tried all means to refresh by re-execute and adding partial triggers.. but nothing is working... It just refresh and I can see that the new bean values are getting updated by checking the size of the bean.. but the Table remains as it is....

Comment: Did you set iterator property in binding to "ifNeeded". You could also rebind the table to the bean created iterator. Or, get the iterator into the binding, not bean if possible. Not sure, this is one of those you just kind of have to hack around at it till it works.